# Comparing ping times in FreeBSD sh

Tags: shell, command-line, text-processing, freebsd

How can I strip the time from a ping return? For example:

```
64 bytes from 10.3.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=2.610 ms
```

I want to grab the value after `time=` and pass it to a test like:

```
if time>=50.0; then do_something; fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you wanted to get just the `time` value without the `ms` label:

```
HOST="127.0.0.1"
PING_MS=`ping -c1 "$HOST" | /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN { FS="=" } /time=/{gsub(/ ms/, ""); print $NF; exit}'`
```

This gives me:

> `0.058`

Now, if we wanted to test if `time>=50.0`, we could use `awk` for this, too, since POSIX `sh` itself can't compare decimal numbers:

```
if echo $PING_MS | awk '{exit $1>=50.0?0:1}'; then
    echo "Ping time is >= 50.0ms."
fi
```

You could shorten this to:

```
if ping -c1 "$HOST" | /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN { FS="=" } /time=/{gsub(/ ms/, ""); exit $NF>=50.0?0:1}'; then
    echo "Ping time is >= 50.0ms."
fi
```

`FS` is the Field Separator, and `$NF` is always the last field. `$NF>=50.0?0:1` will exit with a success exit code if the last field is `>=50.0`; or an error exit code if not. `/time=/` matches only lines that contain `time=`. `gsub(/ ms/, "");` removes `" ms"` from the string.

Comment: "POSIX sh itself can't compare decimal numbers" - do you need this? I think "time=2.610 ms" can be 2 (`floor(2.610)`) so you can compare integers :)

Comment: I can't think of a simple way to compare a float/decimal in POSIX-compliant `sh`.  I wanted to point out that you can't just do `if test "$PING_MS" -ge "50.0"; then` ...

Comment: Wow! Even more than I hoped for. Thank you.